# Java - Failed to Load the JNI shared Library (JDK)

Tags: java

I am trying to launch an application (not Eclipse) that was written in Java. When I do, I get an error that says "Failed to Load the JNI shared Library (JDK)" along with a path that points to the location of the file.

From searching Google and StackOverflow, all I can find are people saying that the Java version installed needs to match my machine. My machine is 64 bit and so is my java installation, so I don't think that is my issue.

I have also verified that C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin is in my path variable. Also, just for the record, I do not use Eclipse. I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling Java an the application that was written in Java. Lastly, the file it is complaining about exists on the machine.

Does anyone know what else could be the cause of this problem?

Update:

Thanks for your responses. I got it resolved, but the resolution seems like more of a hack and goes against what I was reading earlier. I installed the 32 bit version of Java 7 along side of my 64 bit version of Java 7. I then added the path the 32 bit version to the system path variable.

After I did this, the application was able to launch. Is there an issue with having both 64 bit and 32 bit versions of Java 7 installed simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

This is an error from your application. The application uses JNI. It is complaining that it cannot load it. Why it says (JDK) only its author knows. You will have to ask the author.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem having both versions of Java installed.  However, the application you were using probably shipped with a 32-bit version of the JNI library.  So, it needed to be used with a 32-bit Java JRE.